# Mysql Connection lost to localhost

Tags: mysql, localhost

When I was running a query in Mysql, it suddenly stopped working.
After I restarted my computer I have lost all my connections to my previously built databases, localhost[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMKbk.jpg), Please help me, how can I get back those databases and tables?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your server is stopped, you need to start it.

Open your windows command prompt and type:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Steve.. thanks for your answer,, but it doesn't help at all. no changes

Comment: Nothing changed? as in your server is still stopped?

Comment: Hi Again Steve, no that didn't help but I received an answer from a friend that "This usually happens when we only download the partial components of mysql and not the complete package, because of which the mysql server installed on our system does not start automatically" so I just deleted the last table I had created from the C: drive , then restarted Mysql from Controlpanel/Administrativetools/Services and now everything is ok. Thanks for your help.